# MVC Maintaining Model through multi view form submits

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am working on a MVC which is basically three steps.

Create a view for each step i.e.
StepOne
StepTwo
StepThree

On step one and two I ask the users to enter some details.

All the values for the multiple step I store in one Model.

And getting from StepOne to StepTwo is fine. Certain values in my model are being set and maintained.

But on StepTwo when I do my second httppost and pass the model, it seems to just create a new instance of the model and values from stepone are not maintained.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("StepTwo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "restrictionForm" }))   { %>
<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
<div id="wrapping" class="clearfix">
    <h3>Postcode Restriction Type : </h3>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedRestriction, Model.RestrictionTypes,"Select Restriction...", new { @class = "selmenu required" }) %>
    <h3>Restriction Description : </h3>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RestrictionDescription, new { @class = "txtblock required" }) %>
</div>
<section id="buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" />     
</section>
```

And in my controller

On Page Load my Model is still intact and still maintains values from previous step.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult StepTwo(PostcodesModel model)
    {
        var summaryMessage = "";
        model.SummaryMessage = summaryMessage;
        model.RestrictionTypes = _Provider.GetRestrictionTypes();

        return View(model);
    }
```

But at the Httppost, the model has lost values and seems to have created new instance of model.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("StepTwo")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult StepTwoPost(PostcodesModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any idea how I can maintain model between Http Posts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your question that you believe models persist across requests. This is not true.

You either pass information to the view via your model from the controller, or submit values from your view to your controller and MVC handles this by binding html form inputs to your View Model.

If you want to persist your View Model across each step you need to take the values accepted and copy them into a new model (or directly inject it) when calling your new view.

Something like this (I just typed this up off my head so its not clean but should give you an idea):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StepOne()
    {
        var model = new MyNewModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    /* NOTE THE MODEL PASSED BACK HERE IS NOT THE EXACT SAME OBJECT
    AS THE ONE CREATED IN THE GET ACTION ABOVE, MODEL BINDING HAS OCCURRED 
    TO READ YOUR FORM INPUTS AND MATCH THEM TO A NEW MODEL WHICH IS EXPECTED */
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StepOne(MyNewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something here

            // pass model to new view
            TempData["model"] = model;
            return RedirectToAction("StepTwo");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StepTwo()
    {
        MyNewModel model;

        if (TempData["model"] != null)
        {
            model = (MyNewModel) TempData["model"];

            // make some changes if necessary
            model.MyProperty = 2;
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("StepOne");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, found something that worked. In my second Http Post I can add my existing Model Values which are then persisted. <% using (Html.BeginForm("StepTwo", "Home", Model , FormMethod.Post, new { id = "restrictionForm" }))   { %>

Comment: Good stuff. If you find a value is not persisted when posted back it may need adding as a hidden field. For example if you output someone's name and just call @Model.Name in your view, this will not get bound back on a POST back to the Name property, unless you add a hidden input @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)

Comment: ok nice, yeah I just noticed that when I added the model to my form declaration all the values of my model are displayed in the url like query string objects which is not nice

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also keep your model in Session ( per application ) or in a ViewState ( per page ).

Every time you make a post you upgrade the session. It's also optimal because on the client side you receive only a session identifier.

Some differences between Session and Viewstate:

1. `Session` is per application, while `ViewState` is per page
2. `Session` sends to the client side only a session identifier, while `ViewState` sends an ecrypted text